# MSSQL Subquery Return Values

Tags: sql-server

I need a query that returns 'True' if the following query returns a value that is less than 45.

```
select sum(assignmentPoints) as Points from Assignment a join Studies s
on a.courseCode = s.courseCode and a.assignmentName = s.assignmentName and a.sectionName = s.sectionName and pnr = '851326'
where assignmentPoints > 45
```

I also want the query to return 'False' if that value that query returns is more than 45, if that query returns 'null' in other words.

Could anyone help me out?

/////Edit

Do you know if it is possible to turn that query into a function instead? Like the function would return False or True depending on the query.

/////Edit

M.Ali and huMpty duMpty came up with the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select CASE 
           WHEN  sum(assignmentPoints) > 45 
             THEN 'TRUE'
            ELSE 'FALSE' 
       END as Points 
from Assignment a 
join Studies s  on a.courseCode     = s.courseCode 
               and a.assignmentName = s.assignmentName 
               and a.sectionName    = s.sectionName 
               and pnr              = '851326'
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to turn that query into a function instead? Like the function would return False or True instead of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function. *I have used the same code from M.ALi*

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_FunctionName
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PNR VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result BIT =0 

    select @Result = CASE 
               WHEN  sum(assignmentPoints) > 45 
                 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END
    from Assignment a 
    join Studies s  on a.courseCode     = s.courseCode 
                   and a.assignmentName = s.assignmentName 
                   and a.sectionName    = s.sectionName 
                   and pnr              = @PNR


    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Comment: I removed the "as Points" which for some reason made assignmentPoints a invalid column. But as I removed it, it worked as a charm! This was a great solution! I salute both of you fine sirs! Thank you M.Ali and huMpty duMpty! I would upvote but I can't.

Comment: @Reality-Torrent: Of course you don't need the alias here :)